# How do I perform brute force function verification inside a function when running Rust tests?

Tags: testing, rust

When I'm testing functions that have an obvious, slower, brute-force alternative, I've often found it helpful to write both functions, and verify that the outputs match when debugging flags are on. In C, it might look something like this:

```c
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef NDEBUG
#define _rsqrt rsqrt
#else
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#endif

// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root
float _rsqrt(float number) {
    const float x2 = number * 0.5F;
    const float threehalfs = 1.5F;

    union {
        float f;
        uint32_t i;
    } conv = {number}; // member 'f' set to value of 'number'.
    // approximation via Newton's method
    conv.i = 0x5f3759df - (conv.i >> 1);
    conv.f *= (threehalfs - (x2 * conv.f * conv.f));
    return conv.f;
}


#ifndef NDEBUG
float rsqrt(float number) {
    float res = _rsqrt(number);
    // brute force solution to verify
    float correct = 1 / sqrt(number);
    // make sure the approximation is within 1% of correct
    float err = fabs(res - correct) / correct;
    assert(err < 0.01);
    // for exposition sake: large scale systems would verify quietly
    printf("DEBUG: rsqrt(%f) -> %f error\n", number, err);
    return res;
}
#endif

float graphics_code() {
    // graphics code that invokes rsqrt a bunch of different ways
    float total = 0;
    for (float i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        total += rsqrt(i);
    return total;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%f\n", graphics_code());
    return 0;
}
```

and execution might look like this (if the above code is in tmp.c):

```
$ clang tmp.c -o tmp -lm && ./tmp # debug mode
DEBUG: rsqrt(1.000000) -> 0.001693 error
DEBUG: rsqrt(2.000000) -> 0.000250 error
DEBUG: rsqrt(3.000000) -> 0.000872 error
DEBUG: rsqrt(4.000000) -> 0.001693 error
DEBUG: rsqrt(5.000000) -> 0.000162 error
DEBUG: rsqrt(6.000000) -> 0.001389 error
DEBUG: rsqrt(7.000000) -> 0.001377 error
DEBUG: rsqrt(8.000000) -> 0.000250 error
DEBUG: rsqrt(9.000000) -> 0.001140 error
4.699923
$ clang tmp.c -o tmp -lm -O3 -DNDEBUG && ./tmp # production mode
4.699923
```

I like to do this in addition to unit and integration tests because it makes the source of a lot of errors more obvious. It will catch boundary cases that I may have forgotten to unit test, and will naturally expand to the scope to whatever more complex cases I may need in the future (e.g. if the light settings change and I need accuracy for much higher values).

I'm learning Rust, and I really like the natively established separation of interests between testing and production code. I'm trying to do something similar to the above, but can't figure out what the best way to do it is. From what I gather in [this thread](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/ifdef-like-feature/1753/13), I could probably do it with some combination of `macro_rules!` and `#[cfg!( ... )]` in the source code, but it feels like I would be breaking the test/production barrier. Ideally I would like to be able to just drop a verification wrapper in around the already defined function, but only for testing. Are macros and `cfg` my best option here? Can I redefine the default namespace for the imported package just when testing, or do something more clever with macros? I understand that normally files shouldn't be able to modify how imports are linked, but is there an exception for testing? What if I also want it to be wrapped if the module importing it is being tested?

I'm also open to the response that this is a bad way to do testing/verification, but please address the advantages I mentioned above. (Or as a bonus, is there a way the C code can be improved?)

If this isn't currently possible, is it a reasonable thing to go into a feature request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it feels like I would be breaking the test/production barrier.

Yes, but I don't get why you are concerned about this; your existing code *already* breaks that boundary. You can use [`debug_assert`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.debug_assert.html) and friends to ensure that the function is only called and verified when debug assertions are enabled. If you want to be doubly-sure, you can use `cfg(debug_assertions)` to only define your slow function then as well:

```
pub fn add(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    let fast = fast_but_tricky(a, b);
    debug_assert_eq!(fast, slow_but_right(a, b));
    fast
}

fn fast_but_tricky(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    a + a + b - a
}

#[cfg(debug_assertions)]
fn slow_but_right(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    a + b
}
```

---

I don't like this solution. I prefer to keep the testing code more distinct from the production code. What I do instead is use *property-based testing* to help ensure that my tests cover what is important. I've used [proptest](https://crates.io/crates/proptest) to...

- [Compare a Rust implementation against C](https://github.com/shepmaster/twox-hash/blob/v1.5.0/comparison/src/lib.rs#L51-L57)
- [Compare a SIMD implementation against standard](https://github.com/shepmaster/jetscii/blob/v0.4.4/src/simd.rs#L388-L397)

I usually take any cases that are found and create dedicated unit tests for them.

In this case, the proptest might look like:

```
pub fn add(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    // fast but tricky
    a + a + b - a
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::*;
    use proptest::{proptest, prop_assert_eq};

    fn slow_but_right(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
        a + b
    }

    proptest! {
        #[test]
        fn same_as_slow_version(a: i32, b: i32) {
            prop_assert_eq!(add(a, b), slow_but_right(a, b));
        }
    }
}
```

Which finds an error with my "clever" implementation in less than a tenth of a second:

```
thread 'test::same_as_slow_version' panicked at 'Test failed: attempt to add with overflow; minimal failing
input: a = 375403587, b = 1396676474
```

Comment: I realize the boundary was already broken in my C code, I was just hoping there was a better way to do it. I like the verification strategy instead of random inputs because it feels like a stronger guarantee that the output is always going to be correct, as opposed to random inputs which might miss something. Especially with computational geometry stuff, it's easy to miss colinearity edge cases for example. `debug_assertions` might be the way to go for me, thanks.

Comment: @user3476782 frankly, I don't follow how your usage is substantially different from arbitrary / randomized testing. You are relying on whatever values trickle in from a higher level of your code to drive your assertion. I especially don't get how your style guarantees that the *output* is correct, compared to property-based testing. Both approaches rely on what input comes in to the function and the implementation of the testing oracle. Note that property-based testing doesn't have to be **random** — you can configure it to explore whatever search space is useful.

Comment: It doesn't help you guarantee that it will work on all inputs, but at least if your code fails somewhere, the debugger stops in the right place because of the broken assumption. It especially makes it easier to track down the source of logical errors.